# Bitmap.Save problems

Tags: .net, compact-framework, bitmap, save, steganography

can anyone tell me if you know to be a problem with Bitmap and steganography for WM 6?

I am working on a project and i have to hide a digital signature in a bitmap. The algorithm works perfect, as in untill i have the image on the memory the bitmap contains the modified bytes.
But after i save the image (Bitmap.Save()) and I reopen the image, than those bytes are lost. When i say lost i mean they are the orriginal bytes from when the picture was taken.

Thank you.

here is the Save method:

```
    {
        if (miSave.Enabled == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, no image is opened. ", "Save Error");
        }
        else
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

            sfd.Filter = "Bitmap|*.bmp|JPEG|*.jpg";

            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                if (sfd.FileName != "")
                {
                    Bitmap origImage = pictureBox.GetBitmap();
                    ///just a test to see that the bytes are the modified ones..and they are
                    byte[] origImageByte = ImageProcessing.ConvertBitmapToByteArray(origImage, origImage.Height * origImage.Width +54); 
                    origImage.Save(sfd.FileName, formatOfImage);
                    MessageBox.Show("Succesfully ", "Image Saved");

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

and the open method

```
    {
        if (pictureBox.Visible == false)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

                dlg.Filter = "Bitmap|*.bmp|JPEG|*.jpg";

                if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);


                    initialSize.Width = img.Width;
                    initialSize.Height = img.Height;

                    imageOpened();//this just does does some enabling buttons nothing more

                    pictureBox.SetBitmap(img, pixelSize);
                    pictureBox.ShowImage(img);

                    trackBar.TrackBarPosition(lblMinVal, lblMaxVal, this.Size);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Failed loading image");
            }
        }
```

}

Comment: Post some code - are you sure you have updated the original image and are saving that? Or are you creating a new image and ending up saving the original?

Comment: But where is the code that changes the bytes?  My bet is that you're not saving what you think you're saving.

Comment: I am sure i am saving what i need to save....if you look up there in the Save meth code i rececked to see the bytes of the image and it's the correct data.

i am just modifing the LSB. 
Please correct me if i am wrong: but if bmp has no compression at all than any modification should be kept right?

Comment: What colour depth are you using? Given you're saving the image from the control, could it be that the data has been cropped if running in 15 bit colour mode (for example)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that you're only modifying the LSB.  I assume you mean the least-significant-byte (and not least significant *bit*), if there is such a thing.

The standard `Bitmap` in .Net is 32-bits-per-pixel, with 1 byte each for the R, G and B components, and 1 byte for the alpha-channel, which is usually interpreted as transparency in devices that support transparency.

It's possible that you're only modifying the alpha-channel value, and since Compact Framework picture boxes don't support transparency (I think), the `Bitmap` looks exactly the same as it did originally.

Try modifiying some different bytes, and you should see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First, "Least significant bit" is actually correct.  The least significant bit is the least significant bit in each of the R, G, B and perhaps A channels, each of which contain one byte in a 32-bit bitmap.

Second, you posted the "Save" and "Open" code - could you post the code in which you actually change the bitmap data?  If you did not modify the bits **in the pictureBox object** then you are indeed simply saving the original image, as that is where the open method puts the data.